# Trouble with using defmulti dispatch function

Tags: clojure

I have written this multi function in clojure.

```
(defmulti printlmt (fn [s] (> (count s) 10)))
(defmethod printlmt true [s] (println s))
(defmethod printlmt false [s] (println (take 10 s)))
```

I then try to execute it as below..

```
(printlmt "test")
```

But, I keep getting the following error.

```
IllegalArgumentException No method in multimethod 'printlmt' for dispatch value: 4  clojure.lang.MultiFn.getFn (MultiFn.java:156)
```

In my understanding the anonymous function should return a value of `true`. Why is the anonymous function returning 4?

If I call the dispatch function separately, like this

```
((fn [s] (> (count s) 0)) "test")
```

In this case it returns `true`!

Edit:
I'm adding the terminal text which I have:

```
startingclojure.core=> (defmulti printlmt (fn [s] (> (count s) 10)))
nil
startingclojure.core=> (defmethod printlmt true [s] (println s))
#object[clojure.lang.MultiFn 0x3315fe88 "clojure.lang.MultiFn@3315fe88"]
startingclojure.core=> (defmethod printlmt false [s] (println (take 10 s)))
#object[clojure.lang.MultiFn 0x3315fe88 "clojure.lang.MultiFn@3315fe88"]
startingclojure.core=> 

startingclojure.core=> (printlmt "test")

IllegalArgumentException No method in multimethod 'printlmt' for dispatch value: 4  clojure.lang.MultiFn.getFn (MultiFn.java:156)
startingclojure.core=>
```

Comment: Your code works for me

Comment: @Lee I added the actual console text. Could you see if there is something wrong.

Comment: No problem too with both code. have you tried quitting and then rebooting repl ? Stupid question but maybe an old false definition of printlmt is still here

Comment: You're right. My bad. It works after restarting repl.

Comment: Although, I'm not able to correct the definition. Every correction of defmulti seems to require a repl restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to restart your repl for redefining a method, use `remove-method`

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/remove-method

```
(remove-method printlmt true)
```

then redefine.

**EDIT**
You can use

```
(ns-unmap *ns* 'printlmt)
```

**note:** `ns-unmap` will require redefining all your methods as well.

Comment: Thanks! This works, and also (remove-all-methods multifn). This still doesn't help me to redefine the defmulti dispatch function. I try defmulti again with a different function, but still it works the old way. For example, in my case, I changed the switch length from 10 to 5. Still the "true" method is called upto length 10.

Comment: Thanks! ns-unmap worked! However, and probably this is a different question, I couldn't find how to list all the def methods inside a defmulti. The methods don't show up on calling dir on the namespace. And calling source on the multi method name doesn't help either.